# Close Component Dialog Programmatically Angular 2

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

In my Angular 2 Application, I've a component that I'm using as screen and as a dialog/popup as well. 
This is my HTML

```
<app-dialog [(visible)]="showDialog">
 <div>
    <ng-template #container>
    </ng-template>
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="!showDialog">
    {{removeComponent(popUpComponent)}}
 </div>
</app-dialog>
```

Here is my TS file code where I am adding a component as child...

```
this.showDialog = !this.showDialog;
this.popUpComponent = AdmissionIntimationComponent;
this.addComponent(this.popUpComponent);
```

In my `AdmissionIntimationComponent`, I'm adding reference to this component like this in constructor;

```
constructor(private dialogRef: DialogComponent)
```

Now, When I open this `AdmissionIntimationComponent` as popup, It works perfectly fine, But when I open this as a separate screen, It gives me this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AdmissionIntimationComponent -> DialogComponent]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AdmissionIntimationComponent -> DialogComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for DialogComponent!

And If I don't use `Dialog` reference in constructor, this error goes away but I'm unable to close dialog programmatically.

Is there any way to resolve this error or close dialog programmatically??

Comment: only service can inject through the constructor. not components

Comment: Can I close a component through service?

Comment: You can use a `Subject` that hold the communication between your main component and the dialog. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts